# Display content from a file in color

Tags: php, css

I want to display the content from a file to a Textarea but i want the content to be colorful when displayed in the Textarea..Can anyone tell me how to set colors to the content in the file ??

Suppose I have 2 different files A.txt and B.txt and i want to display content from A.txt in RED and content from B.txt in BLUE in a single text area. Does anyone have an idea about that??

Comment: You can use seperate `<span>`'s with different classes assigned to it. That would work.

Comment: `if file==A.txt { // use this.css file }` (type of scenario).

Comment: Make 2 textarea's that look like one?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one color for a `textarea`'s text through CSS.

```
textarea { 
  color: #f00; }
```